# default_get records from data file

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

how can i pre load records from data by default_get method.

i have data file with this kind of records  data/project_data.xml

```
<record id="project_document_type_gal" model="project.part.template">
        <field name="code">ŪK</field>
        <field name="sequence">49</field>
        <field name="group_id" ref="project_custom.project_document_kv"/>
        <field name="description">UK (UK)</field>
    </record>

    <record id="project_document_type_sem" model="project.part.template">
        <field name="code">SEM</field>
        <field name="sequence">50</field>
        <field name="group_id" ref="project_custom.project_document_kv"/>
        <field name="description">SEM (SEM)</field>
    </record>

class ProjectPartTemplate(models.Model):
    _name = 'project.part.template'
    _inherit = 'project.object'


class ProjectObject(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'project.object'
    _rec_name = 'code'

    sequence = fields.Integer('Sequence')
    code = fields.Char('Code', required=True)
    description = fields.Char(required=True)
    project_default_stage = fields.Boolean(
        'Default for new projects',
        help='Will be used for new projects', default=True)
```

and wizard.

```
class ProjectPartWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'project.part.wizard'
    _description = 'Part wizard'

    part_ids = fields.Many2many('project.part')

    @api.model
    def default_get(self, fields_list):
        result = super(ProjectPartWizard, self).default_get(fields_list)
        part_ids = []
        if self._context.get('active_model') == 'project.project':
            project = self.env['project.project'].browse(
                self._context.get('active_id'))
            project and part_ids.extend(project.project_part_ids.ids)
        # TODO load all part from template
        result.update(part_ids=[(6, 0, part_ids)])

        return result
```

UPDATE

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='task_count']/.." position="before">
                    <button string="Generate Parts" class="oe_stat_button"
                            name="%(project_part_wizard_action)d"
                            type="action" icon="fa-th">
                    </button>
                </xpath>
```

here is button

so there is a templates and i need to that all templates would be in wizard pre-loaded when i open it. how can i do it with default_get

Comment: Use the context when opening the wizard from a button then pass them as `default_field_name`.

Comment: there is 50 records in data, and i need to preload them when wizard is opening. can you give a code example?

Comment: Can you at least give the method called when you click on the button and the model where this method belong to.

Comment: when i click on the button just tree view opens. and i want that in that tree view records from data would be pre-loaded

Comment: Please add only one tag for a version you're using

Comment: Compute them before redirecting to the wizard.